# Console.ReadKey echoing unexpectedly with Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm having a problem using `Console.ReadKey()` with `Thread.Sleep()`. I wrote the following method as a replacement for `Console.Readline()` with the added functionality of being able to be interrupted.

```
public static string Readline()
{
    Interrupted = false;
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    string input = "";
    do
    {
        while(!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);

            if(Interrupted)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(Interrupted)
        {
            break;
        }

        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if(input.Length > 0)
            {
                input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input += keyInfo.KeyChar;
            Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        }
    }
    while(keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    Console.WriteLine();

    return input;
}
```

The problem here is that calling `Thread.Sleep()` causes `Console.ReadKey()` to echo the key pressed, even though `true` is passed in to `Console.ReadKey()` to disable echoing. The key pressed is *supposed* to be echoed by the `Console.Write()` call further down, so what actually happens when the program runs is that each key echoes twice.  When I remove the call to `Thread.Sleep()`, everything works as it should, however CPU usage shoots up to 100% while it's waiting for `Console.KeyAvailable`.

Here's what I've already tried:

- Removing the `while(!Console.KeyAvailable)` and placing all the code in the loop, except the `Thread.Sleep()` and the interrupt check, inside of an `if(Console.KeyAvailable)`
- Adding another `Thread.Sleep()` right before and after the call to `Console.ReadKey()`
- Removing the `Console.Write()` call that echoes the pressed key.  Each key *does* only echo once, however backspace no longer works.
- Placing the interrupt checking loop containing the `Thread.Sleep()` in a separate thread and waiting on an `AutoResetEvent` in the main loop containing the `Console.ReadKey()`
- Running the method asynchronously and using `await Task.Delay()` in place of `Thread.Sleep()`

None of these have fixed the issue.  Is there anything I could do to make `Console.ReadKey()` work as intended, such as an alternative to `Console.ReadKey()` or `Thread.Sleep()`?  To put it simply, what I need is something that can limit CPU usage while waiting without causing `Console.ReadKey()` to echo keypresses when it shouldn't.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do with this code?

Comment: @xxbbcc The purpose of the method is to emulate the functionality of `Console.Readline()`, but to allow other threads to interrupt it while it's waiting for input.

Comment: Like what? If a thread puts something into the console, it may interfere with what users type. Why don't you flip this and just use `Console.ReadLine()` and do your work on background threads? What do you gain by emulating console functionality? (Old DOS programs that didn't use an interrupt were running at 100% CPU for this same reason.)

Comment: Possibly related: [Strange behaviour of Console.ReadKey with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15143931/1220550)

Comment: @xxbbcc The problem with that is that, as far as I know, there is no way to interrupt `Console.Readline()`, it will run until enter is pressed.  If I need the program to stop recieving input, `Console.Readline()` won't allow for that.

Comment: I pasted your method into a test project here, and I am unable to repro your issue with `Sleep()`. With or without it, I see each character echoed one time as expected.

Comment: Look at this answer then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221829/682404

Comment: Also, the interrupt logic is broken. If `Interrupted` becomes true, program execution ends up at `Console.ReadKey(true)`, which blocks if there's no key in the buffer. I assume `Interrupted` is intended to cause the method to immediately return whatever input has been received so far?

Comment: Also also, strings are immutable, so the += operator is not the best approach for concatenation. You should use a StringBuilder to receive input characters.

Comment: @glenebob Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question to fix it. I had it correct in my code but I accidentally deleted it while messing around with it.